# Setting file contexts on /proc files

Tags: linux, security, selinux, proc, lsm

I want to restrict access to files in `/proc` as much as possible using SELinux. When I try to chcon a directory in `/proc`, it fails:

```
$ chcon -t staff_proc_t /proc/acpi
chcon: failed to change context of '/proc/acpi' to ‘system_u:object_r:staff_proc_t’: Operation not supported
```

Apparently, the `/proc` filesystem does not allow changing the context directly. How can I set SELinux contexts on `/proc` entries?

If that is not possible, I would like to prohibit access to these files by other means. I would like to hide mountpoint information, ACPI directory, `/proc/config.gz` etc.

Answer (score 0):

One of options is to write a wrapper filesystem using FUSE that provides access only where it is needed. (I leave this answer here just because it is possible, but quite cumbersome solution.)